# string to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string like this:

**3/4/2013** or like this **11/10/2012**. This is in mm/dd/yyyy format which I want to convert to MM/dd/yyy. I am doing like this:

```
 DateTime publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is throwing me an error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

What is going on here?

**EDIT:**

After reviewing all the answers, I want to show Month and Day of the DateTime variable.

So I cannot do something like this:

```
 string publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Having a string will not solve my problem because I am using this variable to show only day and month.
When I tried parsing this *'publicationDate'* back to DateTime is truncates the '0's from month and day.

Hope I made my point here.

**Answered:**

```
string publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd");
```

Comment: That is not my question. My question is 3/4/2013 to MM/dd/yyyy. How do I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer: you should use "M/d/yyyy" in ParseExact.

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. It has all custom strings for date time. d and dd are different as are M and MM.

Comment: "This is in `mm/dd/yyyy`". It's not, realize that lower case 'm' stands for minutes.

Comment: I edited my answer again: just apply a .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") to the result of the ParseExact, and you will get the expected formatted date.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I need a DateTime variable, not string.

Comment: To extract Day and Month of a DateTime, you can use the .Day and .Month properties of publicationDate. Both will return an integer. Otherwise, you can also use .ToString("MM/dd") to display month and day only. Hope it helped.

Comment: It helped a lot Laurent. Thanks for your input. Please see my edited question. I wrote the snippet which worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped you. There is a lot of other possible DateTime formatting as @roughnex pointed in his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add leading zeroes to the month and day.

This way: 04/03/2013

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
                     "03/04/2013", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If leading zeroes are a problem, then do:

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
                     "3/4/2013", 
                     "M/d/yyyy", 
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Finally, if you want to add leading zeroes:

```
string myFormattedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                "3/4/2013", 
                                "M/d/yyyy", 
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                             .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I dont have the control, the date is coming from the database.

Comment: @Laurent what about `11/4/2013`?

Comment: True! My data can be in 2/3/2013 or 11/10/2014.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: not a problem, 4 november 2013. ParseExact is performing very well.

Comment: @Laurent sorry, my bad, catch +1

Comment: Basically, I want to add a '0' whenever there is a single month.

Comment: @RG-3 add '0' where? Result of parsing is a DateTime object

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I want to show for 2/12/2012 like this: 02/12/2012.

Comment: With this answer it is like: 2/12/2012.

Comment: Got it: re-edited with a solution to display the date with leading zeroes.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I need a DateTime variable, not string.

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern instead: `"M/d/yyyy"` to parse it and `"MM/dd/yyyy"` for `ToString`:

```
DateTime publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// if you want to display two digits for day and month:
Console.WriteLine(publicationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

It works for both as you can see here: http://ideone.com/M7luBD

Comment: This is giving me: 2/3/2012. I want this as: 02/03/2013.

Comment: @RG-3: Edited my answer, the first question is how to parse it correctly, the second is how to diplay it with two digits.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I need a DateTime variable, not string.

Comment: @RG-3: It's still unclear, a `DateTime` variable has no format. If you want to show only the day and month use it's `Day` or `Month` properties or use `ToString("dd/MM")`

Comment: @RG-3: So was the answer `ToString("MM/dd")`?  It would have helped if you'd have shown the desired output in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution was this:

```
string publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd");
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string `ToDateTime` first. Make sure you have leading zeroes.

```
string date = "03/04/2013";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [TestCase("3/4/2013", 3, 4, 2013)]
    [TestCase("11/4/2013", 11, 4, 2013)]
    public void DateTest(string date, int month, int day, int year)
    {
        var publicationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual(day, publicationDate.Day);
        Assert.AreEqual(month, publicationDate.Month);
        Assert.AreEqual(year, publicationDate.Year);
    }
```

Both test cases pass.

---

If your format asks for MM/dd/yyyy then you need to supply the string as such (04/03/2013 instead of 4/3/2013). So either

- use M/d/yyyy if your supplied date is without leading zero's
- or use the MM/dd/yyyy if you can supply leading zero's